# Match exact word/string in begining, in between & end in string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

[image]

Here I need to match exact word but I am getting all results I used '%' + columnname + '%' in wildcard.

I am looking for exact word match doesn't matter it is beginning, in between and end of string.If i try to match 'America', I should be able to get 1st row as output.

Comment: Please **always** include the version of your server - answers can frequently depend on it! Edit the tags!

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Match 'America' only - `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Word LIKE '^America' AND Word Like 'America$';` Probably very inefficient! :-)

Comment: If you need to test for exact match use CHARINDEX. If you check for a word at the beginning, check it is 1, if not, simply check it is non-zero.

Comment: String can be anything like 'The America USA Arizona' and I have 'America' , 'America USA', 'USA America' in my table so it should be match with 'America' only.

Comment: *it should be match with 'America' only.* Why it shoud NOT match to  'America USA'? 'The **America USA** Arizona'...

Comment: yes it should not match with 'America USA' as I have one master table that contains 'America', 'America USA' so when I join using wild card for 'America' it is returning multiple rows, I don't need multiple records since it's matching with both string 'America' and 'America USA'